# Node.js spawn for command-line?

Tags: command-line, external-applications

I need blender command-line access though `spawn` but keep running into an `ENOENT` error and it is hard to pinpoint what is missing.  The command-line being passed in the sample application works in terminal.

Below are some details about the environment and the sample script I am using.

---

**Environment (OSX El Capitan)**

1. Installed Blender 2.76b with:

   `brew install Caskroom/cask/blender`
2. Then add `alias` to `bash_profile` for terminal access:

   `alias blender="/Applications/blender/Blender.app/Contents/MacOS/blender"`

**Test Code**

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
var child_process = require('child_process');
var arguments = [
        '-b',
        'recipe.blend',
        '-o', 'test-#',
        '-f', 0
];
console.log("values: ", arguments);
var child = child_process.spawn('blender', arguments);

child.stdout.on('data', function(data) {
    console.log('data out: ', data.toString());
});
child.stderr.on('data', function(data) {
    console.error('error out: ',data);
});
child.on('close', function(code) {
    console.log('closing code: ' + code);
});

// Raw command-line for terminal. (PASS)
// blender -b recipe.blend -o test-# -f 0
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try changing the `child_process.spawn('blender', arguments);` line to `child_process.spawn('/Applications/blender/Blender.app/Contents/MacOS/blender', arguments);`.  NodeJS won't be using your bash aliases, so unless the `blender` executable is in its `PATH` it won't be able to find the executable and will throw an `ENOENT`.

The other option is adjusting Node's `PATH` to include the path to the blender executable.  You could also pass the fullpath to the blender executable in as an environment variable.

Cheers!